Invoke QBusiness chat sync API with identity-aware credentials from Java
I am trying to invoke AWS QBusiness chat sync API through Java SDK. I used to be able to do this before enabling identity centre (IDC) based auth on the app by just assuming an IAM role with Admin permission. But after enabling IDC I get the following error:
Method threw 'software.amazon.awssdk.services.qbusiness.model.AccessDeniedException' exception.
...
User ID must be null and identity-aware credentials must be passed for identity-center enabled applications

How do I pass identity-aware credentials? I have IDC properly set up and can log in to QBusiness app's chat experience. I just need to figure out how I can do the same from a Java application.
